Barycenter of a triangle using integration
Problem definition
Consider a triangle with vertices $\{V_i=[\xi_i\,\,\eta_i]'\}_{i=1}^3$. As is well known, the barycenter (or centroid) $g$ of a triangle coincides with the mean of its vertices, so that \begin{equation} g\triangleq\frac{V_1+V_2+V_3}{3} \end{equation}
I want to show that the barycenter is the solution of the following "continuous average"
\begin{equation*}
\tilde{g}\triangleq \frac{\int_{\mathcal{T}} z \text{ d}z}{\int_{\mathcal{T}} \text{d}z}
\end{equation*}
where $\mathcal{T}\subseteq{\mathbb{R}^2}$ is the set of points $z$ belonging the area encircled by the triangle. In other words, I want to prove $\tilde{g}=g$.
My attempt
In order to compute such integral I want to use the following specific parametrization
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
z(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)&\triangleq (1-\sqrt{\alpha_1})\,V_1+\sqrt{\alpha_1}(1-\alpha_2)\,V_2+\sqrt{\alpha_1}\alpha_2V_3 \\
&=[(V_2-V_1)+(V_3-V_2)\alpha_2]\sqrt{\alpha_1}
\end{aligned}
 \qquad \alpha_1,\alpha_2 \in[0,1]
\end{equation*}
Accordingly, the integral at the numerator of $\tilde{g}$ becomes
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\mathcal{T}} z \text{ d}z = \int_0^1\int_0^1 \underbrace{[(V_2-V_1)+(V_3-V_2)\alpha_2]\sqrt{\alpha_1}}_{=z(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)}\,\left|\textrm{det}\left[\frac{\partial z}{\partial \alpha}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)\right]\right| \text{ d}\alpha_1\text{ d}\alpha_2
\end{equation*}
while the integral at the denominator of $\tilde{g}$ becomes
\begin{equation}
A\triangleq \int_{\mathcal{T}} \text{ d}z=
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \left|\textrm{det}\left[\frac{\partial z}{\partial \alpha}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)\right]\right| \text{ d}\alpha_1\text{ d}\alpha_2
\end{equation}
where $\frac{\partial z}{\partial \alpha}$ is the Jacobian of the previous parametrization.
The first step is to compute the Jacobian which, if I'm not wrong, is given by
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial z}{\partial \alpha}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2) =\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{(V_2-V_1)+(V_3-V_2)\alpha_2}{2\sqrt{\alpha_1}} & (V_3-V_2) \sqrt{\alpha_1}
\end{array}\right].
\end{equation}
Next, its determinant is
\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}
\textrm{det}\left[\frac{\partial z}{\partial \alpha}\right]&=
\textrm{det}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{(V_2-V_1)+(V_3-V_2)\alpha_2}{2\sqrt{\alpha_1}} & (V_3-V_2) \sqrt{\alpha_1}
\end{array}\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\textrm{det}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
(V_2-V_1)+(V_3-V_2)\alpha_2 & (V_3-V_2)
\end{array}\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\textrm{det}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
(V_2-V_1) & (V_3-V_2)
\end{array}\right]+\underbrace{\textrm{det}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
(V_3-V_2) & (V_3-V_2)
\end{array}\right]}_{=0}\,\alpha_2\right)\\
&=\frac{\textrm{det}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
V_2-V_1 & V_3-V_2
\end{array}\right]}{2}
\end{aligned}\end{equation*}
which does not depends on the integration variables $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$. Accordingly, the denominator of $\tilde{g}$ simplifies as follows
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
A&=\int_0^1\int_0^1 \left|\frac{\textrm{det}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
V_2-V_1 & V_3-V_2
\end{array}\right]}{2} \right| \text{ d}\alpha_1 \text{d}\alpha_2\\
&=\frac{|\textrm{det}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
V_2-V_1 & V_3-V_2
\end{array}\right]|}{2} \underbrace{\int_0^1\int_0^1 \text{ d}\alpha_1 \text{d}\alpha_2}_{=1}\\
&=\frac{|\textrm{det}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
V_2-V_1 & V_3-V_2
\end{array}\right]|}{2}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Note that we have just found that the Jacobian determinant is equal to $A$. Hence, the numerator of $\tilde{g}$ can be written in the following form
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\int_{\mathcal{T}} z \text{ d}z&= A\,\int_0^1 \int_0^1 
[(V_2-V_1)+(V_3-V_2)\alpha_2]\sqrt{\alpha_1} \text{ d}\alpha_1\text{d}\alpha_2\\
&=A\,\left[(V_2-V_1)+(V_3-V_2)\underbrace{\int_0^1 \alpha_2 \text{ d}\alpha_2}_{=\frac{1}{2}}\right]\underbrace{\int_0^1 \sqrt{\alpha_1}\text{ d}\alpha_1}_{=\frac{2}{3}}\\
&=A\,\frac{V_3+V_2-2V_1}{3}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
In conclusion, I get the following result
\begin{equation}
\tilde{g} = \frac{A\,\frac{V_3+V_2-2V_1}{3}}{A}=\frac{V_3+V_2-2V_1}{3}
\end{equation}
which is pretty close to $g$, but not equal. Where did I go wrong?

The issue is with the second line in $z$. You are missing a $V_1$ term, not multiplied by $\sqrt{\alpha_1}$. If you integrate that, you will get an extra $V_1A$, so your finla answer will be $$\tilde g=\frac {A\frac{V_3+V_2-2V_1}{3}+AV_1}A=\frac{V_1+V_2+V_3}3$$
